# Tap gesture (gesture began) not recognised in Swift

Tags: swift, uigesturerecognizer, uitapgesturerecognizer

UITapGestureRecogniser began state is not recognised, only ended is recognised.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
     let tapgr = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapTrigger(recongizer:)))
     bottomBar.addGestureRecognizer(tapgr)
}

@objc func tapTrigger(recongizer: UITapGestureRecognizer){
        if recongizer.state == .began{
            print("recognised") // does not print
        }else if recogniser.state == .ended{
           print("ended") //prints
        }
}
```

What I am trying to do is highlight a view(not the view the recogniser is added) when a touch is recognised and unhighlight when it is cancelled.

Comment: Tap gesture recognizer is single not continuous. It has no intermediate states

Comment: is there a way to achieve the behaviour mentioned?

Comment: The behaviour mentioned is not well-defined, so you need to define it more clearly. What does it mean for a _tap_ to be "cancelled"?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `UITapGestureRecognizer` you can use `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` to get the different state.

Like this:

```
let tapgr = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapTrigger(recongizer:)))
tapgr.minimumPressDuration = 0
bottomBar.addGestureRecognizer(tapgr)

@objc func tapTrigger(recongizer: UITapGestureRecognizer){
        if recongizer.state == .began{
            print("recognised") 
        } else if recongizer.state == .ended{
           print("ended") //prints
        }
}
```